# NSURLSession 403 response

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I'm sending HTTP Post request using NSURLSession. Although it is not giving error but I'm getting null response in completion handler. Please help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

My Url request looks like this

```
- (void)testUrl {

    NSError *error;
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

   NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.100.4.8080/proposals/addProposal/forJobId/77"]];
    NSLog(@"url : %@",url);
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",500] forKey:@"offeredQuote"];
    [params setValue:@"2016-09-01T12:25:56.000Z" forKey:@"offeredTimeline"];
    [params setValue:@"2016-08-31T12:26:08.876Z" forKey:@"postingTime"];
    [params setValue:@"cohcih khccoh" forKey:@"proposalDescription"];
    [params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",122] forKey:@"userID"];


    NSLog(@"params : %@",params);
    [urlRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                    NSLog(@"response : %@",response);
                                    NSLog(@"data : %@", data);
                                    if(error == nil)
                                    {
                                        NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                        NSError *jsonError;
                                        NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                                                                     error:&jsonError];
                                        NSLog(@"json object ; %@",jsonObject);
                                        NSLog(@"json text ; %@",text);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        NSLog(@"erro : %@",error);
                                    }
                                }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

I'm getting response like this

```
response : <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f97a8e18870> { URL: http://192.168.100.4.8080/proposals/addProposal/forJobId/jobId=77 } { status code: 403, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 21;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    Date = "Wed, 31 Aug 2016 17:30:08 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }
2016-08-31 23:03:11.051 urlTest[66351:323159] data : <20>
2016-08-31 23:03:11.051 urlTest[66351:323159] json object ; (null)
2016-08-31 23:03:11.051 urlTest[66351:323159] json text ;
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the server side (403 Forbidden HTTP status code exists in response to a request from a client to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action.). Check if you can access the URL from another application (eg web browser, terminal, ping), and that will tell you if the problem is in the iOS application itself, or in the server side.

Comment: I tried from  web browser it works fine. So I'm feeling, something is wrong in my code.

Comment: Have you tried to make more simple GET request within your app? You mention, that when you put the link into the browser, it works. SO one reason can be problem in POST method, as opening the link from browser automatically means the method is GET. Or show us the code from API, that is handling your request at server side.

Comment: This method is POST. I tested on Swagger UI. I entered url with jobId and entered required parameters as dictionary. I'm getting response on UI Swagger but here I'm getting null.

Comment: I added full url. You can run this code if you want to see response..

Comment: once try using Postmaster helps to find out exact issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was really silly mistake. I changed base url `http://192.168.100.4.8080` 
to this `http://192.168.100.4:8080` and It started working. If someone is facing similar problem please check your url and parameter. This error is related to server authorization. Most probably there is mistake in url.